# How did these first person plural pronouns come to be in Catalan?

Tags: reference-request, pronouns, catalan

I recently saw [this image](https://external-preview.redd.it/9padDF1UhujfdHuMW-vmyEV3l81Nq6HeWOlaQNRR65E.jpg?auto=webp&s=cc96b0d22a1c8f91dc856448ded3c55422974941) comparing different first person plural masc. pronouns to Pokémon.  For reference the pronouns listed are

- *Nosaltres* (Cat. Central)
- *Natros* (Tortosí)
- *Moatros* (Val. Central)
- *Naltres* (Lleidatà)
- *Noltros* (Mallorquí)
- *Mosatros* (Val. Meridional)
- *Naltros* (Tarragoní)
- *Natres* (Ribagorçà)

This seemed neat because the only one of these I had ever heard of was *nosaltres*, so I went to learn more. Aside from *nosaltres* for which it is easy to find attestation, I was able to find attestation for:

- *mosatros*, *moatros* and *natros*  without citation in a [wikipedium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valencian#Morphology) claiming they are variants used in Valencian. This matches, but is less specific, than the descriptions in the image.  For posterity it says:

  > Several variations for *nosaltres*, *vosaltres* ('we, you'): *mosatros*, *moatros*, *natros*; *vosatros*, *voatros*, *vatros*; also for the weak form *mos*/*-mos* instead of standard *ens*/*-nos* ('us').
- All versions in the image plus some extras in [this forum discussion](https://www.racocatala.cat/forums/fil/27613/nosaltres-natros-mosatros-naltres?pag=1) (this site is in Catalan), but this is super informal and not very informative.  It does tell me that these pronouns, apart from *nosaltres*, are probably considered colloquial.
- All versions in the image plus some extras in the Institut d'Estudis Catalans [*Diccionari Català-Valencià-Balear*](http://dcvb.iecat.net/results.asp?Word=nosaltres&Id=100556&search=nosaltres) (site is in Catalan).  It verifies that these regional variations exists and gives some rather strange example sentences.

At this point though I can't find any more.  It seems that these variations (plus some more) do exist but that's about it.  I would love, though, to be reading more about these, their histories.  In particular which changes happened first or second and which forms diverged from each other. Ideally I would like to be able to make a sort of tree or something like that.

Are there any more informative and scholarly resources about the history of the first person plural pronouns in Catalan dialects? I would suppose that these changes would be a part of larger phenomena ongoing in these languages, so a source does not need to specifically reference this word if it clearly applies.  I would prefer sources in English or Castilian when possible, but I can read Catalan very slowly.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand precisely what you mean by “their relationships and use”? Their internal relationships would seem rather obvious to me: _nosaltros_ or _-es_ is the original, the forms with initial _m-_ have taken that over from the 1pl ending _-mos_, and the rest are varying degrees of whittling down those forms by debuccalisation of s and/or l and subsequent monophthongisations. _N(os)antro/es_ must be nasal assimilation n_l > n_n. As for their use, the IECat page has a very thorough breakdown of which forms are used where – what further are you looking for?

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Well I suppose what seems obvious to you does not seem obvious to me.  Additionally I don't see where the IECat page states their distributions, admittedly I have trouble reading it since it uses its own symbology exacerbated by the fact that I don't speak Catalán.  I am looking mostly for historical information on these pronouns, when did they begin to diverge?  Are they falling out of use? etc.

Comment: The distribution is given in the long paragraph that begins with “Fon.” (i.e., pronunciation). They start off giving pronunciations for _nosaltres_, then say that these are literary forms that aren’t often used in spoken Catalan and that the actually used forms vary by dialect, many dialects having multiple commonly heard forms in free competition or variation. Then they give all the phonetic variants they have collected (in sort of pseudo-IPA) followed by which locations each pronunciation is attested for.

Comment: As for when they started diverging and which are or aren’t falling out of use – of that I have no idea. You should edit that into the question to make it clearer that that’s the sort of thing you’re looking for. Most of the individual developments in themselves I would say are largely too obvious to have much ‘oomph’ for an answer (e.g., the reduction from _nosaltres_ to _no’altres_ to _n’altres_ or _no’ltres_ is pretty self-explanatory), though some are perhaps less obvious (like the initial m in some forms).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Thank you.  I only skimmed the Fon section since I figured it was pronunciation and I didn't understand their notation, that information is useful.  I have tried to update the question to make it more clear what I am looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "the forms with initial *m-* have taken that over from the 1pl ending *-mos*" -- that seems rather implausible IMO (though admittedly I don't have a better explanation).

Comment: @TKR Why is that implausible? The same thing has happened in Irish for example, and in a slightly different way also Sanskrit (if memory serves, with the final _-m_ of _ahám_ being from the secondary 1sg ending _-m_).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Both of those examples seem more natural to me. I don't know the exact facts in Irish, but since Irish is VSO the pronoun would be sitting right next to the ending, while in Sanskrit copying an ending *-m* from verb to pronoun is much simpler than the supposed development in Catalan.

Comment: Another possibility is that the initial *no-* developed an on-glide *nwo-* (as it did in Spanish *nuestro*), and there was then a fusion [nw] > [m].

Comment: Not so quick. "*Next to the widespread PIE interrogative stem \*kwi-, \*kwe-, \*kwo-, there is another interrogative in *m- (Dunkel 2014: 518–523). Although the existence of this interrogative stem is recognised in the literature, it is not well known,* ..." (Michael Peyrot, 2019; called m-Pronomina in a quote from Pedersen). We also find 1st p. sg. and pl. "mir" in Bavarian. Further notions of *me-* in different languages might indicate old heritage. I don't know about that, but found German *mal*, eg. colloquial *lassma'* "let's" compares well.

Comment: @vectory: First-person plural pronouns are not interrogative. German "mir" is thought to be from coalescence of a preceding verb-final nasal with the "w" of "wir": a recent, not an old development.

Comment: @ewawe yes indeed, I'm faintly aware of that, especially the "thought to be". The "interrogative" bit gives me pause, too, hence I refered to pedersen. Also, relative pronomina are a thing. Also cp *many*, Ger *manche* "many", *somanche* "some" on the one hand an En. *some*, *same*, Ger. *sämtlich*, PIE\*sem- on the other hand together with \*sel-, and perhaps \*swe- "self"; and so many more. Further, *wir* from \*kw- would be irregular, but \*k- might be extraneous (n- as well, cp e.g. *nowhereelse but here, with us*); I'm not aware of any internal derivation.

Comment: At any rate, I think I merely implied substrate influence and one possible reason to remain curious

Comment: @TKR in fact Ladino exhibits forms in m here (with the labial on-glide retained) e.g. muestro

Comment: In English we use Encyclopedia and Wikipedia always in the Latin plural form, the singular form looks very weird.

Comment: @jk-ReinstateMonica What do you mean? *Encyclopedia* is singular even in (Neo-)Latin. The second root comes from the Greek word παιδεία, which is also singular.

Comment: @TKR: "Nosaltres" comes from NOS ALTEROS. In his book *Gramàtica històrica catalana*, Francesc de Borja Moll explains that the form MOS instead of NOS was produced by analogy with ME.

Answer (score 7):

The following [isogloss map](https://aldc.espais.iec.cat/files/2017/04/Mapa-1923.pdf) from *L’Atles Lingüístic del Domini Català* details the different pronunciations by region:

[image]

---

[ALDC phonetic symbol guide](https://aldc.espais.iec.cat/files/2019/07/Signes-fon%C3%A8tics-PALDC-vol-7.pdf)

Comment: Any idea what the raised L for 118 means? I’m guessing it means the L is weakened somehow, but I can’t figure out what the comment for 118 means… (Also, what’s up with the stress marks being in the middle of the syllable? That’s weird IPA’ing.)

Comment: You can find [here](https://aldc.espais.iec.cat/files/2019/07/Signes-fon%C3%A8tics-PALDC-vol-7.pdf) the phonetic symbols used in the *Atles Lingüístic del Domini Català*: the raised *l* means that is a barely perceptible sound.

Answer (score 0):

You need a complete set of rules. To find them, perhaps the easiest way would be to find the relevant proto-Occitano-Romance form. On the basis of the other nearby languages

- Occitan: *nosautres* (m.) / *nousaltras* (f.)
- Aragonese: *nusa(l)tros* (m.) / *nusa(l)tras* (f.)

we can confidently reconstruct the proto-Occitano-Romance forms:

**nos-altres* (m.) / **nos-altras* (f.)

We now see that two allomorphies and two frequent elisions between vowels explain all the forms.

---

1. **nosaltres* > *naltres* > *natres*
2. **nosaltres* > **nosaltros* > *naltros* > *natros* (-*os* is allomorphic plural form)
3. **nosaltres* > **nosaltros* > *naltros* > *noltros*

The Valencian forms with *mo*-: *moatros* and *mosatros* have parallel forms in southern Spanish dialects were *nos* > *mos* (because the plural first person desinence -*mos*):

4. **nosaltres* > **nosaltros* > **mosaltros* > *mosatros* > *moatros*

we can see in many of the above forms sporadic elision of /-s-/ and /-l-/ in *nosaltres/-os*.